# C# changing image of a button just paste's the new image ontop of the old image

Tags: c#, winforms, image, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to change the image of a button in different situations.
The only thing it will do is adding the new (smaller) image ontop of the old (wider) image. How can i make sure the old image will be cleared. I can't find button.image.clear or something.

```
if (Global.van_zoek)
        {
            btnterug.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.ZoekBedrijf2));
        }
        else if (!diftext)
        {
            btnterug.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.AlleBedrijven2));
        }
        else if (_Prparent != null)
        {
            btnterug.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.InfoContact2));
        }
        else
        {
            btnterug.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.InfoProject2));
        }
```

http://img225.imageshack.us/i/imageprobl.jpg/

Comment: The button face only clears when a paint event can be handled maybe something is blocking this.
Maybe you have to set the image sizing mode to fillup the button to clear it.

Comment: Change the BackgroundImageLayout to `None` and see what happens. Currently it's in the default `Tile` mode..

Comment: Is it standard button or custom control?

Comment: Not clear on why it didnt worked but I just discarded everything and tried again with below suggestion and it works Thnx every1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Change old image to null
btnterug.BackgroundImage = null;
//Load New Image
btnterug.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.InfoProject2));
```

Comment: I would think that would work but result is the same, see link for result

Comment: @Daanvl I tested it out on a sample app. Works perfectly.

Comment: In my case even simple `button1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.archive_icon;` works perfectly. I suppose that OP have custom writen control

Comment: I'll delete the button altogether and start from scratch with your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Try to use invalidate method:

```
button2.Invalidate();
```

Comment: hmm. I cant repro your error at all. I created a form with two buttons. The second button change pictures on first one circular. One picture is big and another one is small. But picture changing occures clearly. At wich moment you are changing pictures? May be your problem because of programm temporary hanging?

Answer (score 0):

You Could just set the source to null before you change it to the new image.

Comment: sorry maybe I should have mentioned it was winforms app. button doesnt have property source. or do I have to add source manualy?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting [`Button.Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.image.aspx) and [`Button.BackgroundImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimage.aspx) confused?